# ¿Como puedo sumar diferentes cantidad de meses?

Tags: php

Me explico, tengo unas variables las que se encuentran vacias y trato de asignarle el valor que trae otra variable y a esa sumarle 12 meses o 18 meses dependiendo el caso, ejemplo

```
entregaColchon=11-01-2024
```

entonces le trato de pasar ese valor a revisionColchon y a revisionColchon sumarle 12 meses y el resultado deberia ser: 11-01-2025.

acá mi codigo con mis condiciones:

```
$cantidadColchones = ($_POST['cantidadColchon']);
$ultimaCompras = ($_POST['ultimaCompra']);
$recepcionColchones = ($_POST['recepcionColchon']);
$entregaColchones = ($_POST['entregaColchon']);

$cambioColchones = array();
$revisionColchones = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < $cantidadColchones; $i++) {

    $tipoCiudad = current($tipoCiudades);
    $medidaColchon = current($medidaColchones);
    $formaColchon = current($formaColchones);
    $tipoColchon = current($tipoColchones);
    $tipoCamarote = current($tipoCamarotes);
    $recepcionColchon = current($recepcionColchones);
    $entregaColchon = current($entregaColchones);
    $ordenCompra = current($ordenCompras);
    $ultimaCompra = current($ultimaCompras);
    $revisionColchon = current($revisionColchones);
    $cambioColchon = current($cambioColchones);
    $observacionColchon = current($observacionColchones);

    if ($entregaColchon != null) {

        $revisionColchon = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($entregaColchon[$i]."+ 12 month")); 
        $cambioColchon = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($entregaColchon[$i]."+ 18 month"));
    } elseif ($recepcionColchon != null) {
        
        $revisionColchon = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($recepcionColchon[$i]."+ 12 month")); 
        $cambioColchon = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($recepcionColchon[$i]."+ 18 month"));
    } elseif ($ultimaCompra != null) {

        $revisionColchon = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($$ultimaCompra[$i]."+ 12 month")); 
        $cambioColchon = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($ultimaCompra[$i]."+ 18 month"));
    }else{
        $revisionColchon = date('0000-00-00');
        $cambioColchon = date('0000-00-00');
    }

    try {
        //INSERT DE DATOS A LA TABLA inforecambiocolchones
        $statement2 = "INSERT INTO inforecambiocolchones (idInfoRecambioColchones, idCalendarioRecambioColchones, idTipoCiudad, idTipoMedidaColchon, idTipoFormaColchon, idTipoColchon,
        idTipoCamarote, recepcionColchon,entregaColchon, ordenCompra, ultimaCompra, revisionColchon, cambioColchon, observacionColchon) 
        VALUES (:idInfoRecambioColchones, :idCalendarioRecambioColchones,:idTipoCiudad, :idTipoMedidaColchon, :idTipoFormaColchon, :idTipoColchon, :idTipoCamarote, :recepcionColchon, :entregaColchon, :ordenCompra, :ultimaCompra,  :revisionColchon, :cambioColchon, :observacionColchon)";

        $stmt2 = $conn->prepare($statement2);
        $stmt2->bindParam(':idInfoRecambioColchones', $idInfoRecambioColchones);
        $stmt2->bindParam(':idCalendarioRecambioColchones', $idCalendarioRecambioColchones);
        $stmt2->bindParam(':idTipoCiudad', $tipoCiudad);
        $stmt2->bindParam(':idTipoMedidaColchon', $medidaColchon);
        $stmt2->bindParam(':idTipoFormaColchon', $formaColchon);
        $stmt2->bindParam(':idTipoColchon', $tipoColchon);
        $stmt2->bindParam(':idTipoCamarote', $tipoCamarote);
        $stmt2->bindParam(':recepcionColchon', $recepcionColchon);
        $stmt2->bindParam(':entregaColchon', $entregaColchon);
        $stmt2->bindParam(':ordenCompra', $ordenCompra);
        $stmt2->bindParam(':ultimaCompra', $ultimaCompra);
        $stmt2->bindParam(':revisionColchon', $revisionColchones);
        $stmt2->bindParam(':cambioColchon', $cambioColchones);
        $stmt2->bindParam(':observacionColchon', $observacionColchon);
        $stmt2->execute();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die('ERROR: no se pudo llevar a cabo el Listado de Colchones: <br>' . $e->getMessage());
    }

    $tipoCiudad = next($tipoCiudades);
    $medidaColchon = next($medidaColchones);
    $formaColchon = next($formaColchones);
    $tipoColchon = next($tipoColchones);
    $tipoCamarote = next($tipoCamarotes);
    $recepcionColchon = next($recepcionColchones);
    $entregaColchon = next($entregaColchones);
    $ordenCompra = next($ordenCompras);
    $ultimaCompra = next($ultimaCompras);
    $revisionColchon = next($revisionColchones);
    $cambioColchon =next($cambioColchones);
    $observacionColchon = next($observacionColchones);
}
```

***Error de pantalla***

> Warning: Array to string conversion.
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: next(): Argument #1 ($array) must be
> of type array, string

Comment: @gbianchi no me esta entregando el valor que le asigne y no me los está sumando

Comment: hola, tu pregunta le falta codigo, no veo donde sacar la variable $i y al entrar al array: $revisionColchones[$i] no existe por que recien habias declarado: $revisionColchones = array();

Comment: todo estos son errores logicos de programacion ... aun asi, deberias agregar el codigo relacionado y tambien agregar el error que te sale por pantalla, todo esto lo debes colocar el texto, no uses imagenes.

Comment: tambien es importante aclarar que es lo que pretendes hacer con esos if else ... por que la verdad no les encuentro sentido ... aparte que la variable que mencionas: entregaColchon nunca la usas en el codigo... repites el uso de $revisionColchones y no tiene sentido el codigo.

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover hola, he editado mi pregunta, mostrando mas codigo y mostrando los errores que me salen actualmente en pantalla.   Lo que prentendia con mi if es que dependiendo si un valos viene vacio salte a la otra condicion  y haga el calculo de los meses dependiendo de esa condicion.

Comment: sigue haciendo falta codigo ... no veo donde obtienes el array de los dato, por que usas current(), y si al usarlo te da los datos esperados?

Comment: hay te ayude un poco con la edicion de la pregunta

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover Este es la mayoria de mi codigo, lo demas esta en un archivo aparte, para manejar de manera mas ordenada el crud. En caso de que me de los datos esperando debería salir del ciclo al haber insertado los demás datos, lo unico que me causa conflicto es la fecha, ya que dependiendo si hay una fecha de entrega colchon se hace el calculo con la fecha de entrega, sino con la de la recepcion o sino con la de ultima compra o sino devuelve al formulario. Al menos esa es la idea que quiero plasmar.

Comment: y esa idea la plasmaste asi en tu publicacion aya arriba?

Comment: igual, por el error que recibis, ni siquiera llegaste al problema de la fecha.. salvo que de en esa linea... pero ahi el error dice que estas tratando de convertir un array en un string...

Comment: como dice el moderador ... hay algun dato que es un array y lo estas metiendo en un bind param y rompe todo ... por que al bindparam solo puedes pasarle texto en este escenario

Comment: ah ya lo vi... tenes... $cambioColchones = array();.. luego esa varialbe no la usas nunca! y despues haces un bind $stmt2->bindParam(':cambioColchon', $cambioColchones); que es un array vacio, y lo mandas a una variable en tu insert... no se entiende la logica... no creo que podamos ayudarte mas...

Comment: @gbianchi entiendo, ahora creo que encontré una solución.

Comment: Hola. En algunas ocasiones es mejor olvidarse del código y tratar de verbalizar el contexto y lo que intentas hacer. Creo que así podríamos ayudarte mejor. Quizá me equivoque, pero creo que aquí **el principal problema es no saber explicar el problema** y eso ha llevado a escribir un código confuso.